# Count number occurence in Binary Tree

Tags: java, data-structures

Assume a binary tree can have multiple nodes with the same key. Count the number of nodes whose key is equal to a value v. (It's not a Binary Search Tree).

int countVal(int v): returns the number of nodes n where n.key = v

Structure:

```
public class Tree {
    Node root;

    public Tree(Node root) 
        this.root = root;
    }

    public static class Node {
        int key;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        public Node(int key, Node left, Node right) {
            this.key = key;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the way to the solution is to use recursion, but I can't find the right approach.

Comment: I don't see an attempt. Traversing a tree is covered in many tutorials. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/) is one such resource. You can find many such by simple search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution to the problem:

```
public int countVal(int v) {
    if(root == null)
        return -1;
    else
        return countValRec(v, root);
}

private int countValRec(int v, Node node) {
    if(node == null)
        return 0;
    else if(node.key == v)
        return nodeCountValRec(v, node.left) + 1 + nodeCountValRec(v, node.right);
    else
        return nodeCountValRec(v, node.left) + nodeCountValRec(v, node.right);
}
```